# Howto Force TFS 2010 to build a website using the 32bit ASPNET Compiler on a 64 bit build machine

Tags: tfs, aspnet-compiler

We have a very large product that compiles just fine on our 32 bit build controllers and mostly on our 64 bit build controllers with one exception. We have a precompiled web forms front end. When it builds on the 64 bit machine it shows a command line in the log file of
***C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /ourwebapp -p ..\ourwebapp\ -u -f "........\Binaries\Mixed Platforms_PublishedWebsites\ourwebapp\"***
This causes an error because of some 32 bit third part dll's we have:
**ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'Leadtools.Codecs' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. [C:\Builds\5\OurApp\OurApp Build\Sources\Product\Solutions\ourwebapp_ourwebapp.metaproj]**

Does anyone know the correct solution file syntax to force a 32 bit build regardless.
Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Edit you Build Definition and select this option.

```
Process Tab-> Advance->MSBuild Platform->X86
```

Save your build and trigger the build ...

Comment: Amazingly, after trying everything else, this did the trick for me. Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me too. Great stuff

Answer (score 4):

Erik, if you edit your build definition, under the process tab there is the option to set the msBuild compilation x86 or x64 or Auto, setting this to x86 would force the build to perform the compilation in 32 bit.

In the Configurations to Build box, you can specify which platforms and configurations you want to build. (To show this box, expand the Required node, and then expand the Items to Build node.) For example, you can specify that this build should build only the release configuration of the 32-bit version of your C++ project by including Release|x86 in this box. If you leave the Configurations to Build box empty, the default configuration and platform that is defined in each solution or project is built.

See the steps here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx

Comment: I understand this for a 'normal' solution, but in a VS 2010 web project there is only the option for Debug/Release + Any CPU platform There is no x86/x64 or even New option. There is no way to specify for the web site what platforms should be built unless I am missing something.

Comment: - Erik you can configure one by right clicking on the solution and clicking configuration manager. 
- Create a new configuration. Then edit your build definition, you have an option to associate the solution to build, right below that you have the option for configuration to build.