# Trouble building InstallShiel Project with TFS

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, installshield

I currently try to install and configure TFS Build for our TFS Server. With "normal" project like Console Application, Windows Forms or WPF everything is working perfectly fine. But if I try to add a IntallShield Project to my Solution which should build a *.msi File which inherits the output of the Project Files this Error occours in my Build:

> "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.targets" (108):
>   The "InstallShield.Tasks.InstallShield" task could not be loaded from
>   the assembly C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.Tasks.dll. Could
>   not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.Tasks.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format. Confirm that the  declaration is correct,
>   that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the
>   task contains a public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

I already installed InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition onto the built Machine, but the Error still occours.. Anyone know this problem, or a solution?

Marcel

Edit:
The files: "C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.Tasks.dll" and "C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.targets" exist.
Do I need to install Visual Studio onto my build machine?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like TFS is attempting to load InstallShield's 32-bit binaries into a 64-bit process. Try editing your build platform to specify x86. The answers to [Howto Force TFS 2010 to build a website using the 32bit ASPNET Compiler on a 64 bit build machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6782329/89999) describe how to do this.

Comment: Perfect thanks but another Question everytime I now receive a Email Notification about a successful Build the Email itself is in XML Syntax and starts with: An error occurred while formatting the event document (Detailed Message: XSLT compile error.).
Original Event Document:...
Why do I get this Error?