# Error building installshield project with TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, installshield, installshield-2015

I'm trying to build a fairly complex project using TFS that was just upgraded from InstallShield 2013 to 2015 and I got all of the errors except for this one:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2015\InstallShield.targets (77): -7325: An unexpected error occurred validating the architecture for file C:\Users\sa_pgtfs\AppData\Local\Temp\ISCE9F4.tmp\AWSSDK.dll.`

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You could first try to run the build on the build agent manually (with build service account) to narrow down if it's an environment issue.

It's better to make sure the build agent environment is as same as your local develop machine. Such as VS version , InstallShield  version...

Double check if the `AWSSDK.dll` is exist on the build agent.

Another thing is try editing your build platform to specify x86. You could do this follow answer in this question [Howto Force TFS 2010 to build a website using the 32bit ASPNET Compiler on a 64 bit build machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782329/howto-force-tfs-2010-to-build-a-website-using-the-32bit-aspnet-compiler-on-a-64)